# relative position of a line and a plane

Tags: soft-question, vectors, parametric, scalar-fields

determine the relative position of line (d):$( x=2t+3; y=-t+1; z=3t+2)$ and plane (P):$2x-y-z+2=0$ and determine the coordinates of the intersection point if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

substitute the $x,y,z$ of the line in the equation of the plane and solve for $t$. If you have one solution $t=t_0$ , using this value in the equation of the line you find the common point.